# The class 'StreamSink' can't be extended outside of its library because it's an interface class

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am very new to Flutter. I try to run the [flutter_bluetooth_serial 0.4.0](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial) project and it gives me a lot of errors, especially with the versions, so I try to build it step by step, starting with the api it implements for Bluetooth.

Well, in the [BluetoothConnection.dart](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/blob/master/lib/BluetoothConnection.dart) file, line 94, I get an error that I don't know how to solve. It tells me that a class that is used cannot be extended outside its library because it is an interface.

```
/// Helper class for sending responses.
class _BluetoothStreamSink<Uint8List> extends StreamSink<Uint8List> {
  final int? _id;
```

> The class 'StreamSink' can't be extended outside of its library
> because it's an interface class.

So what do I do with that class, how do I implement it, any suggestions?

Why did this work in a previous version of Flutter and now it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

change 'extends' to 'implements'